# Knitr with gridSVG

Tags: r, knitr

Does anybody use gridSVG in Knitr? I found package "gridSVG" provide a device named "gridsvg" and I've written code as follows.

````
 ```{r message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide', dev='gridsvg', fig.ext='svg'}
analysis.runner.result.plot(result, score.table, info.table) # which produces a gpplot
```
````

When I click "Knitr HTML", I got:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not find data file
AnalysisReport_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-61.svg pandoc document conversion failed
```

It seems that the gridsvg didn't produce svg file. I've searched the internet but failed to find any example that uses gridSVG in knitr.

How should I modify the code? (P.S. due to the render quality under windows, I don't want to use the default 'svg' device)

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it is because gridSVG "hacked" the standard `dev.off()` function, and `gridsvg()` is not a standard graphics device, either. I'll test it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: with [**knitr** >= v1.40](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/tag/v1.40), you can ignore the answer below and simply use the chunk option `dev = 'gridSVG'`.

---

Because `gridSVG::gridsvg()` is not a standard R graphics device, you cannot use the `dev` chunk option in **knitr**. The only way at the moment is to manually save the plots, and use a chunk hook to write the plots to your output (see the [knitr graphics manual](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/download/doc/knitr-graphics.pdf)). Here is an example:

````
---
title: Save plots using gridSVG and knitr
author: Yihui Xie
output:
  html_document: default
---

Set up a chunk hook for manually saved plots.
 
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(custom.plot = hook_plot_custom)
```
 
A single plot.

```{r test-a, fig.keep='none', fig.ext='svg', custom.plot=TRUE}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(speed, dist, data = cars)
gridSVG::grid.export(fig_path('.svg'))
```

Multiple plots.

```{r test-b, fig.keep='none', fig.ext='svg', custom.plot=TRUE, fig.num=2, message=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
p = qplot(speed, dist, data = cars)
p + geom_smooth()
gridSVG::grid.export(fig_path('svg', number = 1))
p + geom_jitter()
gridSVG::grid.export(fig_path('svg', number = 2))
```

See the source document of this post at
http://stackoverflow.com/q/23852753/559676
````

See output at http://rpubs.com/yihui/knitr-gridsvg

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation and example. It is really helpful for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it better to use gridSVG, ggsave, rvg or svglite?

Comment: @Yihui: Does this example still work for you? For me, when I run `knit` on the above file, the second two plots are lost. The image files produced are `test-b-11.svg` and `test-b-12.svg`, but the output `.md` file imports images called `test-b-1.svg` and `test-b-2.svg`, which don't exist.

Comment: @Yihui: Thank you! FYI, I was exploring SVG while trying to get anti-aliasing to work in Linux. I finally found out I had a problem with Microsoft font packages as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40940331/5087283 ... now fonts are anti-aliased in PNG (and SVG) and PNG is about 10x smaller and looks just as good, so I'm sticking with PNG. Also the `dev="svg"` chunk option used to cause R to crash somewhere in `knit`, but after installing the font package it no longer crashes. Maybe you didn't want to hear that :)